# Separate base class(template) and derive classes (data).?

Tags: php, oop, pdf, fpdf

General

```
  require('fpdf.php');

  $pdf=new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
  $pdf->Output();
```

I want to separate it two class (base and child(child do with data) )

base class (present the template of output )

```
require('fpdf.php');
class base{
  //TODO
  function def(){
    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();

   // the page header DO IN HERE
      // ->DO IN Derived Class(leave derived to do with data )
   // the page footer  DO IN HERE

   $pdf->Output();

  }
}
```

child class (manipulate the data )

```
  class child extends base{
      //TODO
      function def(){

      $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
    }

   }
```

when call will use the child class for out the `pdf file`

```
$obj_pdf = new child();
$obj_pdf->def();
```

How should I implement it? or it is not possible to this?

Comment: FPDF already helps you with easy header/footer generation. Did you look through the tutorial? http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to accomplish here is a wrapper pattern. I don't know if that is the right solution for your problem. Inheritance is meant to add complexity in the child classes, not extending the functions in the parent.

But for the wrapper you could try something like:

```
class base{
  //TODO
  function def(){
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf=new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // the page header DO IN HERE

    // ->DO IN Derived Class(leave derived to do with data )
    $child = new child();
    $pdf = $child->def($pdf);

    // the page footer  DO IN HERE
    $pdf->Output();
  }
}
```

Call it with:

```
$obj_pdf = new base();
$obj_pdf->def();
```

Comment: Your general idea isn't bad - but you have a couple of stinky items in there. Use `require_once`, not `require`, in case more than one object is constructed. Moving the `require` outside the class definition would be best.

Comment: Don't hardcode which child class to use - parent classes should not know anything about child classes. Instead, have a blank method in the base class, called `write_content` or something, call that one instead of creating a child class, and have the children re-implement that method.